# TypeError: "x" is not a function in node js

Tags: node.js, url-routing, typeerror

I've been trying to add routing to my vanilla node.js server and I've stumbled onto a problem.
Basically I have a router class that has an object attribute that stores all of the routes and their respective handlers and a method called route that takes a request and a response as parameteres and calls the handler for the current req.url and req.method.
The problem is that I get an error saying that my handler isn't a function. Everything will probably be clearer with the source code:

```
    getHandler(method, url) {
        let identifier = this.constructIdentifier(method, url);
        if (!this.endPoints[identifier]) {
            return new Error("Endpoint not registered!");
        }

        let handler = this.endPoints[identifier];

        if (!handler) {
            throw new Error("Handler null!");
        }
        console.log(handler)
        return handler;
    }
```

I've checked using typeof and the handler returned is indeed a function.
Now route:

```
    route(req, res) {
        try {
            let reqUrlString = req.url.split('?')[0];
            let pathName = urlModule.parse(reqUrlString, true, false).pathname;
            let method = req.method;
            let handlerFunction = this.getHandler(method, pathName);
            console.log("TYPE OF HANDLERFUNCTION",typeof handlerFunction);
            handlerFunction(req,res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Now here is where the problem arises. When I test my route in postman, everything goes smoothly but when I try it in the browser I get the following error and output:
TYPE OF HANDLERFUNCTION function
TYPE OF HANDLERFUNCTION object
TypeError: handlerFunction is not a function
(the function still executes and I get results in the browser window but I can't get rid of the error)
The error comes from the line calling the handler function. I've looked online for solutions to this error and similar questions on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to be like my situation.
Any help

Comment: Can you share `this.endPoints` items??

Comment: @Saeed it is an object in which the keys are the paths you want to make requests at.  A good example: if the key is GET./ex and the value should be the handler function that is called when the client makes a get request. Sorry for the late response, I still couldn't figure it out because sometimes I get the error and sometimes I don't, it's very confusing